# Replace all A with B and replace all B with A

Tags: algorithm, replace, language-agnostic

Suppose I want to switch certain pairs of words. Say, for example, I want to switch *dogs* with *cats* and *mice* with *rats*, so that

> This is my opinion about dogs and cats: I like dogs but I don't like cats. This is my opinion about mice and rats: I'm afraid of mice but I'm not afraid of rats.

becomes

> This is my opinion about cats and dogs: I like cats but I don't like dogs. This is my opinion about rats and mice: I'm afraid of rats but I'm not afraid of mice.

The naїve approach

```
text = text.replace("dogs", "cats")
           .replace("cats", "dogs")
           .replace("mice", "rats")
           .replace("rats", "mice")
```

is problematic since it can perform replacement on the same words multiple times. Either of the above example sentences would become

> This is my opinion about dogs and dogs: I like dogs but I don't like dogs. This is my opinion about mice and mice: I'm afraid of mice but I'm not afraid of mice.

What's the simplest algorithm for replacing string pairs, while preventing something from being replaced multiple times?

Comment: In tcl this can be done in a single pass using the function `string map`. For your example it would simply be: `string map {dogs cats cats dogs mice rats rats mice} $text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use whichever string search algorithm you deem to be appropriate, as long as it is able to search for regular expressions. Search for a regex that matches all the words you want to swap, e.g. `dogs|cats|mice|rats`. Maintain a separate string (in many languages, this needs to be some kind of `StringBuilder` in order for repeated appending to be fast) for the result, initially empty. For each match, you append the characters between the end of the previous match (or the beginning of the string) and the current match, and then you append the appropriate replacement (presumably obtained from a hashmap) to the result.

Most standard libraries should allow you to do this easily with built-in methods. For a Java example, see the documentation of `Matcher.appendReplacement(StringBuffer, String)`. I recall doing this in C# as well, using a feature where you can specify a lambda function that decides what to replace each match with.

Answer (score 3):

A naive solution that avoids any unexpected outcomes would be to replace each string with a temporary string, and then replace the temporary strings with the final strings.  This assumes however, that you can form a string which is known **not** to be in the text, e.g.

```
text = text.replace("dogs", "{]1[}")
           .replace("cats", "{]2[}")
           .replace("mice", "{]3[}")
           .replace("rats", "{]4[}")
           .replace("{]2[}", "dogs")
           .replace("{]1[}", "cats")
           .replace("{]4[}", "mice")
           .replace("{]3[}", "rats")
```

Comment: Ah, this solution seems very convenient.

Comment: If your language supports it. One trick I've used in the past is to use non-printable characters as the temporary string: `\0`, `\1`, `\2` etc.

Comment: OP and @slebetman: Unless you're 100% sure that you control what's in the string, this solution is asking for trouble. If the string is user-supplied (or even system-generated in a part of the system you don't completely control), the characters you choose _will_ at some point appear in the input string and cause havoc.

Answer (score 1):

I am admittedly not very familiar with regex, so my idea is to create an array then loop through the elements to see if it should be replaced. First `split()` the sentence into an array of words:

```
String text = "This is my opinion about dogs and cats: I like dogs but I don't like cats.";
String[] sentence = text.split("[^a-zA-Z]"); //can't avoid regex here
```

Then use a for loop which contains a series of if statements to replace words:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if(sentence[i].equals("cats") {
        sentence[i] = "dogs";
    }
    //more similar if statements
}
```

Now `sentence[]` contains the new sentence with words. Some regex magic should allow you to also keep punctuation marks. I hope this helps, and please let me know if anything could be improved.